# How I can write drivers for Android if the support for modules is not an option for the commercial-kernel-phones?

Tags: android, kernel, driver

I see that many Android kernels comes without a loadable module support, how i can write and load a driver in this scenario?

For example i have a codebase for a driver that works under a vanilla linux kernel, how i can port this to Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't -- that's the exact reason there is no support for modules in the commercial phone. If the OEM disables module support, you have no option but to replace the kernel first. If you could just provide a driver, you would have instant unfettered access to the phone, which is what OEMs want to avoid.

Comment: this is just stupid, a support for modules is a big pro for a kernel, they are using linux like a windows-kernel ... well if this is the truth i suppose that i can't do something good to solve this. Where i can find the flags to set and the configuration to compile a modular kernel for android? I see that is not exactly a vanilla kernel, so i'm wondering if there are special flags or a particular build process.

Comment: The kernel is provided for a specific piece of hardware, so you would need to get the kernel source (including its configuration and any patches needed by the hardware) from the device manufacturer. If you're building your own hardware, you will need to start from the Android source and modify as needed for your device.

Comment: yes, i know how to get the proper kernel source for each device, i'm not sure about the build process and how i can set a kernel as modular under Android. For istance Samsung provides a complete kernel source for its devices, there are also many devices supported by the officials android branches, i have all i need, i do not need a step by step guide, i know how to build a kernel and how to use the toolchains, i just need to know how a modular kernel can be set in the config file for Android.

Comment: grep the configs in the vendor source for one with CONFIG_ANDROID entries and perhaps the vendor name as well; this tends to narrow it down to one or two choices.  Also see if the device has a /proc/config.gz  Config options such as enabling modules "CONFIG_MODULES=y" would be the same as on normal linux, and you would have to decide if your module belongs in in the cpio archive alongside the kernel, or if it goes on a filesystem added later.

Comment: Note that it would not matter to most users if the oem kernel on a secured device had module support, since only root can load modules, and that is not a userid available to third party code.  But having module support in the existing kernel would mean that a customized installation might only need to change the userspace, and not rebuild the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a commercial phone and an existing piece of hardware, you are presumably talking about something connected via usb (or else bluetooth or wifi, etc).  For these you can perhaps use the appropriate userspace api.  For example, on phones/tablets that support usb host there is a host api which lets you access a device somewhat like you would with libusb, though there are limitations.

You should of course be able to get the source to the kernel for any device running a linux kernel; that's in the kernel license.  Many vendors are unfortunately slow to make the releases - the glaring problem with source releases is with a bunch of off-label tablets based on chipsets whose manufacturer apparently does not supply kernel and toolchain sources to the device manufacturers, leading to a hand-me-down license violation.

But returning to commercial hardware, typically (in the tradition of Tivo) having the kernel sources doesn't mean that the device will allow you to install the compiled result, or that the bootloader will be willing to execute it even if you manage to flash it.  Fortunately some of the phone manufacturers are getting better about offering developers and power users ways to unlock the bootloader of  personal or test devices - devices sold by Google itself being the leading example.

Comment: let me give you an example: i have succesfully installed Android on my X86 netbook, right now i have a big problem, the keyboard does not function, i mean the netbook keyboard, not a usb or external keyboard, how can i solve this in the commercial world with closed kernel

Comment: Since when is android X86 installed on hardware by you "the commercial world with a closed kernel"?   The idea of a commercial piece of hardware sold to consumers in lock down form is that the software is supposed to work with the hardware; granted there have been issues at times, but your example is not an example of this at all.

Comment: ok, what if i want to offer an "unlocked" version of the same driver? For example many brands cut down the features of a driver, many do not give a good GPU hardware acceleration, what you are saying it's true but not completely, each brand consider each device as product to sell and they cut down the features because they hope to sell something in the future and add something more into the next device. I think that a better driver can give more value to your device.

Comment: Feature-enabling may be true of consumer hardware in general, but it almost works the other way on things with a linux kernel; ie, often you can only get the GPU to work by using the binary blob driver/driver-helper.  For more general-computing leverage-the-linux capabilities though (especially those which might have been crippled by a re-seller, or left out due to release deadlines), a rebuild is a  great idea - this is, *if* you or your target audience can install it.